# Simple image css attribute issue

Tags: html, css, image

I have a question regarding bunch of images.

I have the image path and try to load them in my browser.

some of them have css style sheet shown in my Chrome browser like the following

```
element.style {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

but some of my images have the css style like

```
element.style {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
}

img[Attributes Style] {
  width: 1275px;
  height: 963px;
}
```

I load these images simply using the address like

> http://www.testproject.com//image/test.png

Why do some of images have width and height set? Can I remove them?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare the following 2 `img` tags in **[this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Fft8j/show/)** in your Chrome dev tools.

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/GTUxoqj.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/GTUxoqj.png" width="200" height"200">
```

The following style

```
img[Attributes Style] {
  width: 200px;
}
```

only appears on the 2nd attribute and appears in the Chrome dev tools on a grey background because it's not coming from CSS styles in the document or from an external stylesheet. The second image has a width and height attribute set on it. The dev tools are showing you that for that image the width is being affected by the attribute value *(as opposed to CSS style)*. The grey background means it's not a CSS property you can modify through the dev tools. Chrome has similar behavior for default styling it applies to certain otherwise unstyled elements.

Comment: so there is not way to redefine the default setting unless I manually setup the css style in style sheet? Am I correct? thansk!

Comment: From what you describe your image is un-styled with the exception of the width & height attributes. So yes, you would need to specify some sort of styling targeting the img tag. You can also google "customize chrome user-agent stylesheet" to learn how you can write a CSS file on your local machine that would override the (blank) defaults Chrome is providing you for that `img` tag.

Answer (score 1):

From the sounds of it. You're images are picking up the Chrome's user stylesheet. Here is a some good info on the [user select property](http://www.css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/). Since any css you load should overwrite these styles when present, you can do one of the following...

**Add width/height attributes to the image tag**

```
<img src="http://www.testproject.com//image/test.png" height="100" widith="100">
```

or

**Add a class to control the size**

```
HTML
<img src="http://www.testproject.com//image/test.png" class="test_image">

CSS
.test_image {width:100px;height:100px;}
```

Hope that helps!